# Does dlang install some signal handlers by default

Tags: linux, signals, d

I have infinite loop program written in D:

```
$ cat dprog.d 
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;

void main()
{
  while(1){
    Thread.sleep(dur!("seconds")(1));
  };
}
```

When I build and run this program on Linux (Ubuntu), `kill -10 $PID` has no effect on it. And indeed, it does catch a bunch of signals by default:

```
$ cat /proc/$PID/status | grep SigCgt
SigCgt: 0000000180000a00
```

Signal 10 is a `SIGUSR1` signal, for which the default action is process termination (consult `man 7 signal`).

Equivalent program, written in C terminates on `kill -10 $PID` and its `cat /proc/$PID/status | grep SigCgt` is `SigCgt:    0000000000000000`.

Equivalent program, written in Rust also terminates on `kill -10 $PID`, however its `cat /proc/$PID/status | grep SigCgt` is `SigCgt:   0000000180000440`.

My question is: does D (Rust) compiler register default signal handlers? If yes, why? Also, is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs for [core.thread.thread_setGCSignals](http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/core.thread.thread_setGCSignals.html) tell us that, on Posix systems, SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 are used for the runtime to control suspending and resuming threads for GC purposes.

This function allows you to change which signals are used, in case there are different signals you don't need.